# Возникла проблема при загрузке приложения в Play Market

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-manifest, google-play-console

Попытался загрузить apk файл, появилось следующее сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что именно мне нужно поменять в манифеcте, чтобы загрузка прошла успешно?
Мой манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.semenov.dollarrate">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно выбрать Android App Bundle вместо APK и всё тогда заработает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]